# How to get the properties of jQuery ui's plug-in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the properties of jQuery ui's "sortable" from the outside of jQuery ui.

I have tried

```
console.log(jQuery.ui.sortable.items);
console.log(jQuery.sortable.items);
console.log(sortable.items);
console.log(jQuery.ui.sortable.options.items);
```

and so on, but none of them works as I aimed.
Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-option) to get and set options associated with a sortable instance.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "items" );
```

If you want all associated options you can omit the option name

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "option" );
```

And setting an option value is as simple as adding a third parameter containing the value.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "items", "> li");
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [the API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items):

```
var items = $(".selector").sortable("option", "items");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to access the properties of sortable from the outside though the property I wanted to get was empty... Both  answers are great, and it's really difficult to choose the most helpful answer, but I will choose the Dave's one which has the getter code and the official link as the one. Hope somebody thumbs up Brian's answer.

Comment: Mine has all three possible usages, a link to the API for options, thorough explanation and was here first. Not sure how you decided this was a better answer because the only other factor is that he has 93k reputation. :)

Comment: @Brian While I agree yours is more complete, I'm not sure it's worth any sort of rebuttal. As far as "firsties" go, IIRC the difference was sub-minute.

Comment: @Brian Lol. If it makes you feel any better, I had a comment suggesting that yours be accepted but my phone blew up before the request was completed.